# React Typescripted Higher order component loses generic prop type of the passed component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, higher-order-components

I have an input component that accepts a name property that is generic that extends a string type (I don't recall how this type is called, but it results in a type of that string value)

A simple example would be

```
type SuperType<T extends string> = T;
const value: SuperType<'test'> = 'test';
```

This results in value being of type 'test'.

Now when I wrap my component into a higher-order function like in the code below, I lose the strict type, and the generic fall back to a type of string.

The code example has comments that showcase the issue. If I call the component by itself onClick function gets a property of type 'Input' but the input wrapped inside a Higher-order component gives a property of type string.

```
import * as React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const Input = <T extends string>(props: {
  name: T;
  onClick: (name: T) => void;
}) => {
  return (
    <input
      name={props.name}
      onClick={() => {
        props.onClick(props.name);
      }}
    />
  );
};

const inputHoC = <T extends object>(Component: React.FunctionComponent<T>) => (
  props: T
) => {
  return <Component {...props} />;
};
const InputWithHoC = inputHoC(Input);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Input
        name="Input"
        onClick={inputName => {
          //** here inputName is of type Input */
        }}
      />
      <InputWithHoC
        name="Input"
        onClick={inputName => {
          //** here input is of type string */
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Sandbox link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-chatterjee-p52ct?file=/src/App.tsx

My question is why does this happen and how to retain the strict type.

Answer (score 1):

```
const InputWithHoC = inputHoC(Input);
```

What's happening is that the type for `InputWithHoc` is evaluated once at this line and it becomes:

```
const InputWithHoC: (props: {
    name: string;
    onClick: (name: string) => void;
}) => JSX.Element
```

The `InputWithHoc` is *not* generic.  It is the function `inputHoC` that is generic.

We want to switch that around.  The `inputHoC` function should not be generic, but it should return a generic component.

I'm kind of blanking right now on how to do this is a more generalized way, if it's even possible, but here's how you do it for your input:

```
// interface for props which depends on T
interface InputProps<T> {
  name: T;
  onClick: (name: T) => void;
}

// type for a generic input
type GenericInput = <T extends string>(props: InputProps<T>) => JSX.Element;

// HOC takes a generic function component and returns a generic function component
const inputHoC = (Component: GenericInput): GenericInput => <T extends string>(
  props: InputProps<T>
) => {
  return <Component {...props} />;
};
```

Now your `onClick` callback knows that the type of `inputName` is `"Input"`.